# How to deploy public IP resource on local network

Tags: linux, networking, bgp

I would like to know how to get traffic for our public IPs routed to the ISP device (actually, the L2 switch connected to the ISP device).

My organisation was just assigned a public IP range by our RIR. Our physical network layout is:

```
ISP device --> L2 Switch --> Ubuntu Server [/29 IP from ISP] (gateway, firewall, proxy)
```

Google points to ASNs and route objects but I am unfamiliar with the deployment process. How do I deploy the public IP on the local network?

Comment: The most simple way to do this would be to set up 1:1 NAT and required port forwards for the device on your network that will be using the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

If your public IP is assigned by a RIR (eg. ARIN, RIPE, etc.), you have a public ASN most probably, and you should peer with one or more ISP (Single-Homed, Stub-Multi-Homed, Multi-homed) rather than having a simple subscription. Basically you need to agree the peering policies (ie. BGP parameters) in this case.

Otherwise, if it's your ISP that has assigned you a public IP (that is the most common case actually), the ISP takes care of all the things above. What you need to in this case is a simple NAT/PAT configuration on the router connected to the ISP (most probably).

In other words, in this last case, it's up to the ISP driving the traffic from internet to your router, and you need just take care of the path between your router and your server.